# Need windows video player with seek preview feature

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, media-player, preview

I am looking for a windows video player with the seek preview feature, like the one in the Hulu player described as follows: "Seek Preview displays a preview thumbnail when the mouse hovers over a spot in the timeline". Any ideas? I haven't noticed this feature in the major video apps like WMP and VLC.

Comment: what version of windows video player do you currently have?

Answer (score 4):

MPC BE (Media Player Classic Black Edition) has that feature.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpcbe/

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Does the thumbnail preview work with m3u playlist / remote streaming?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a video editor instead. A lightweight one. Say, something which is only meant for basic cutting and slicing. Absent a truly hardcore nonlinear video player (tm) it's what I am personally using. I would recommend Solveigmm Video Splitter, because it's relatively fast.

I suspect online services like Hulu or YouTube can be much faster about seek previews because they cache the previews. Solveigmm unfortunately does not do this. You'll have to wait for the previews to load everytime you load the video file, and everything you zoom in to a level further than you have been working at.

Comment: I’m voting this up because I did something similar. I recently got a TV tuner for my desktop, but I cannot run the TV program because it requires .NET 4.5 which I don’t have/want installed. I use VirtualDub to watch TV with the tuner, but then I wrote an elaborate AutoHotkey script to turn GraphEdit of all things into a full-fledge, feature-rich TV-viewing program. ☺

Comment: I tried downloading this Solveigmm Video Splitter, but it is no longer available. Then, I installed the new version of Wondershare Filmora and it does not show the preview as youtube does.

Answer (score 1):

Global Pot Player has this feature as well - i think it works better than it does in MPC-BE and KM Player. You can find it [here](https://potplayer.daum.net/)

to enable go to Preferences...playback....display thumbnail previews.

Comment: I tried KMPlayer, MPC BE and Pot Player under Windows 10. Found Pot Player to be the best, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thanks! Pot player version `220914 (1.7.21801)` is the only solution that works in 2022/Oct.

Answer (score 0):

New `KMPlayer` has this feature.

You can move the mouse cursor on the time bar to view a thumbnail of that position right away on the screen. The video itself plays on, and the main purpose of the feature is to provide you with better seeking options in the player as you can use it to preview the video position without jumping to it right away.

Change log : http://www.kmplayer.com/update/update/main/11

[image]

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail to this answer. Have you used this application before? Thanks

Comment: Does the thumbnail preview work with m3u playlist / remote streaming?

Comment: KMPlayer removed this option in the latest x64 version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pnK3sat3p4. Also, google chrome is blocking KMPlayer download so I don't trust to install it anymore: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6261569